# Python BeautifulSoup how to extract var result from javascript element?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, esprima-python

I'm new with Python and I've been trying to use BeautifulSoup to extract one particular data line from a variable defined in a script element.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import esprima

#----------------some comment'

URL = 'https://downdetector.com/status/facebook/'

browser = {'user-agent': 'my agent'}


#--------------some comment:
page = requests.get(URL, headers=browser)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


#---------------some comment:

chart = soup.find("div",{"class":"popover-container justify-content-center p-relative"}).script.get_text()
print(chart)
```

OUTPUT:

```
var data = {
status: 'success',  
baseline: 29,       
communicate: null,  
company: 'Facebook',
max: 66,
series: [

                      { x: '2020-05-30T13:22:28.168484-04:00', y: 25  },

                      { x: '2020-05-30T13:37:28.168484-04:00', y: 27  },

                      .....

                      { x: '2020-05-31T13:07:28.168484-04:00', y: 30  },

                  ]
                }

                $(function () {
                  chartThis(data, 'holder', 'line')
                });

                if (data.communicate && $('#dd-communicate').length) {
                  $('#dd-communicate').html('<div class="border text-left d-inline-block p-2"><i class="fa" aria-hidden="true" style="color: red; width:16px; height:12px; background:url(https://cdn2.downdetector.com/d328eb8cbe4e164/images/v2/message.svg) no-repeat"></i>'
                    +'<span class="d-inline-block px-1">'+ data.company+' &bull;  ' + moment.utc(data.communicate.created_at).fromNow()
                    + '</span><p class="font-weight-bold my-0">'+ data.communicate.message + '</p></div>')
                }
```

Do you know an easy way to extract the 'max' value from the var result above?

I've tried using esprima, but still no luck as I've hit error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:/test.py, line 31, in 
>       if token["type"] == "Identifier" and token["value"] == "max": TypeError: 'BufferEntry' object is not subscriptable

My code with esprima looked like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import esprima

#----------------some comment'

URL = 'https://downdetector.com/status/facebook/'

browser = {'user-agent': 'my agent'}


#--------------some comment:
page = requests.get(URL, headers=browser)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


#---------------some comment:

chart = soup.find("div",{"class":"popover-container justify-content-center p-relative"}).script.get_text()

tokens = esprima.tokenize(chart)

token_iterator = iter(tokens)

for token in token_iterator:
    if token["type"] == "Identifier" and token["value"] == "max":
        value_token = next(next(token_iterator))
        result = value_token["value"]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution to extract the max value would be to use `split` on the `chart`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://downdetector.com/status/facebook/'
browser = {'user-agent': 'my agent'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=browser)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


chart = soup.find("div",{"class":"popover-container justify-content-center p-relative"}).script.get_text()
max_val= chart.split("max: ")[1].split(",")[0]

print(max_val)

OUT: 64
```

Comment: Nico, thanks for your quick answer!

With this information, I've tried to automate an email to my inbox and I've received an error:

"  File "c:/test.py", line 46, in <module>
    if (max_val < 50):
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'"

Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: you can use int(max_val) < 50  (split returns a str)
If this solves your question it would be great if you can mark it as answered (gray checkmark next to the answer)

Comment: Yeah, I think I might need to raise another question for the second part as you've initially answered the original question - thanks a lot.

After adding int(max_val) > 50 it still gives the same error. :(

I'll leave additional code in the next comment:

Comment: "import smtplib

if int(max_val > 50):
        send_mail()

def send_mail():
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()

    server.login('email', 'pw')

    subject = 'test'
    body = 'test/'
    msg = f"Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}"

    server.sendmail(
        'from email',
        'to email',
        msg
    )
    print('succesfully sent')

    server.quit()"

Comment: No worries! it should be  `if int(max_val) > 50:` 
Alternatively, you can do `max_val = int(max_val)` to always have max_val as an integer value in your program

Comment: Oh wow that's a quick fix haha - it worked! Thank you so much, Nico. :)